# How to add dynamic content block in right side bar of magento

Tags: magento, block

I want to add a block of content in right side bar which will be dynamic based on customer's login status.

For example if the customer is not logged in I have to show create account and login button there in the right side bar.

if the customer is logged in then I have to show other buttons.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout XML ([which you know how to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6354227/471559)) use the layout handles `customer_logged_in` and `customer_logged_out`. Inspect the existing `customer.xml` layout file to see examples.

Answer (score 1):

The Magento way of knowing if a customer is logged in is: `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()`.
If you need help on something else, please be more specific.
HTH

Answer (score -1):

First, in php code, you should know the customer's login status, get values from cookie or session, depending on your login method.

Then, you can show different html blocks by the customer's login status, like this:

```
if($has_login){
   include("login_page.html");
} else {
   include("not_login_page.html");
}
```

Also, if you want to load these content dynamic, you can use ajax to get these html codes, and adopt to show at right place.

Comment: I know how to do in PHP but the Magento is different case. This is not true for magento