# adding additional template into right sidebar magento

Tags: php, magento

I just tried to add addtional template file to include a block of content in right side bar but get failed.

Below is my effort

added in local.xml file

```
<reference name="right">
   <block type="cms/template" name="right.side.template">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>callouts/right_template.phtml</template>
    </action>                
   </block>
</reference>
```

I also tried this

```
<block type="cms/template" template="callouts/right_template.phtml"/>
```

and created a template file callouts/right_template.phtml.

But it is not loading the template file content in right side bar.

How do I go about? I have cleared the magento cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it myself I was using wrong type `type="cms/template"`. This should be `type="core/template"`

```
<block type="core/template" template="callouts/right_template.phtml"/>
```